# How do I type [ and \ with a Mac keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook, mac, vmware-fusion

I am using a Mac with an [Apple Wireless Keyboard - French](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184F/B).

I have installed Ubuntu as virtual machine by `VMware Fusion`. The keyboard setting of Ubuntu is as follows:

[image]

And the preview is not exactly as [Apple Wireless Keyboard - French](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184F/B):

[image]

In Mac, we can type `\` and `[` by:

- \ = <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>
- [ = <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

However, it doesn't work under Ubuntu. Could anyone tell me how to type `\` and `[` under Ubuntu? Also, is there a keyboard other than `French`, that I currently set, which fits better my Mac keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm setting on a macBook pro - same keyboard pretty much!

I've switched my layout to My Language [Macintosh] - now i can make:

`[` `]` ← <kbd>RightAlt</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> & <kbd>RightAlt</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>
`{` `}` ← <kbd>RightAlt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> & <kbd>RightAlt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
 
`\` ← <kbd>RightAlt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

So it's pretty much the best solution i found, as it makes it manageable by doing it as windows normally do, but it's sorta off from the normal mac way.

On a side note i have my <kbd>Cmd</kbd> button mapped with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and made some changes so it functions almost like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> button in OS X. - This way i lost the <kbd>Super</kbd> key but it's more to my liking ;)

Comment: This was not enough for me in Ubuntu 19.04. It might be because I am using a Norwegian keyboard, but I had to install `gnome-tweaks`, then go to the "Keyboard & Mouse" section, then turn on "Show Extended Input Sources", then restart `gnome-tweaks` and go back to the same section, then click on `Additional Layout Options`, then click on `Key to choose 3rd level`, then choose Right Alt. After that, the keyboard combinations in your answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For a single occasion I would resort to Unicode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> for left bracket and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> for backslash.

For a long-term answer we'd want a single keypress, but I'm just not sure how to get your layers of software to align.

Answer (score 0):

Did you gave a try to Keyboard-configuration?

In my case (Ubuntu 12.04 server on MacBookPro 10.9 within VirtualBox 4.3.8 (ok, not Fusion, but similar conditions right?), here is what I did:

sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

```
keyboard-configuration choices for MackBookPro French keyboard:

1. MacBook / MacBookPro (Intl)
2. French
3. French (yes, again)
4. Right Alt (AltGr)
5. No Compose Key
```

Seems keyboard settings works fine and are keep after reboot.

I may have to tests some other parameter value for 2. 3.and 5.

It took me 5 minutes to find out the right parameters for you: hope it will be that fast for you

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> should work.